# Can I call a UNIX script from Nant on an XP machine

Tags: nant

I have installed TeamCity and what to call a UNIX script from a step in it using using Nant. Done a simple test to see that I can call a Nant build that simply writes a test message. Now I am tring to build the code to call a Unix script and cannot find anything of use on the WEB. Does anyone know if it can be done?

Thanks

Angus

Comment: You mean you are running Windows XP and want to execute Bash scripts? Do you want to run them on a remote machine, or locally?

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP can't execute Unix scripts, so nant can't do it either.

You can install cygwin which can execute Unix scripts and then use that through nant's exec task.

Something like:

```
<exec program="c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" commandline="--login -i myscript.sh" />
```